# Create Nativescript with typescript project but not angular

Tags: nativescript

How can I create a nativescript project with typescript enabled?

No need for Angular feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tns create myApp --template tsc
```

This will create basic NativeScript project with TypeScript enabled - You are good to go!

p.s. Note that when working with TypeScript project, by default your files will be transpiled to *.js  but you should always work and make changes in your *.ts files (any changes made in *.js files won't be applied to your project)

Answer (score 0):

Create vanilla JS project install typescript as global and then instead of .js file create .ts during building it will transpile to js files which will be used in app later. Or you can combine them, some files can be done with typescript and others can be done with simple js

Comment: Is there a way for generating ts files when doing "tns create". Referring to the initial template starter files.

Comment: I think no but you can create them after initial create

Comment: there is a pre0defined tsc tempalte . see this answer for the code http://stackoverflow.com/a/38954989/4936697